# nodejs reverse counting (increment/decrement)

Tags: jquery, node.js, animation, easing, fading

I write a litle animation lib wiht the jquery easing functions.
Now i have the problem when my start value is greater or equal as the end value, my function dosnt work.

```js
var easing = require("../easing.js").ease;


function fade(start_value, end_value, duration) {

  var interval = 46;
  var time = 0;


  setInterval(function () {

    // calc current time
    time = time + interval;

    // call easing lib
    value = easing["linear"](time, start_value, end_value, duration);
    value = Math.round(value);
    
    if(value >= end_value){
      clearInterval(this);
      console.log("Done");
    }
    
    console.log(value);

  }, interval);
}


fade(255, 0, 1000); // 255 immediately
fade(0, 255, 1000); // 0 to 255 in 1s
```

I want when the start value is greather then the end value a decrement count.
How can i make this with the easing lib ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide a working code snippet? I get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line

```
  if(value >= end_value){
```

Here, you're written it with the assumption that you're going UPWARD toward `end_value`. Instead, the line should be agnostic to the fact of whether or not `start_value` is greater or less than `end_value`. Your function should read like:

```
function fade(start_value, end_value, duration) {

  ...

  var min_value = Math.min(start_value, end_value);
  var max_value = Math.max(start_value, end_value);

  ...

  // Stop the animation when out of range
  if (value <= min_value || value >= max_value) {
    clearInterval(this);
    console.log("Done");
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this dosnt work. Here the source from the "easing" method "linear": `function linear(t, b, c, d) { return  c * t/d + b; }`, i think the problem is this function, if you call this function like "linear(0, 255, 0, 1000)" it returns immediately "255"